# Setting chosen font family works in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have this code to retrieve the font family of a certain text div, in order to set that to the drop-down (SELECT) font-picker of my editor:

```
    //getter for fontFamily
    function getFontFamily(inner) {
        var fontFamilyVal = $(inner).css("font-family");
        console.log('current font family is ' + fontFamilyVal)
        $("select#fontFamily option").each(function() {
            this.selected = (this.value == fontFamilyVal); 
        });
    };
```

However it doesn't always work in Chrome. It only works with font names without spaces, when I have a font family whos name has spaces it fails (but works fine in firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A debug statement helped out...

```
console.log('current font family is ' + fontFamilyVal)
```

...and revealed that Chrome adds ' around the font name if that name has spaces in it (firefox does not). So here is how I amended my code to work also in chrome:

```
    //getter for fontFamily
    function getFontFamily(inner) {
        var fontFamilyVal = $(inner).css("font-family");
        console.log('current font family is ' + fontFamilyVal)
        $("select#fontFamily option").each(function() {
            if( (this.value == fontFamilyVal) || (this.value == "'"+fontFamilyVal+"'") ) {
                this.selected = true;   
            }
        });
    };
```